# jquery and asp.net gridview help

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I have a grid with a link and what I want to achieve is when the link is clicked, to open  a modal window. My modal is working properly. I'm just having issue with getting the link to do something. Below is my example code.

**ASPX:**

```
<asp:GridView AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="100%" ID="grvUsers" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# eval("ID") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**HTML render:**

```
<table cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="grvUsers" style="width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse;">
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">Delete</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span id="grvUsers_Label1_0">23</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('td:nth-col(0)').click(function(){
        alert("OMG");
    });
});
```

Comment: Where in that HTML do you see a `<tbody/>` element?

Comment: does it work with built-in jquery selector `:first-child`. what is the result of just `$('td:nth-col(0)')`, do you have a result ?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to add the event with js can you just use :

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="Label1" onClick="myAlertFunction();" runat="server" Text='<%# eval("ID") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
```

I would recommend you check out this jquery documentation: 
[Jquery Dialog w/Modal](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal)

Comment: ok, so when I call that function, how do I display the modal? Or should I say how do I call jquery from javascript function? sorry, I'm a noob.

Comment: @jack Is this a question about capturing a click event, or a question about how to design a modal popup?

Comment: capturing an event. what i want to happen is when the link is click, it opens the modal window.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can just use ajax for the modal popup, works a whole lot better than using jquery library(there are exceptions..)
2. You can use the a select command field as a delete and handle the event in your SelectIndexchanging or Delete either one.

Add this to your gridview

```
<asp:CommandField HeaderText="Delete" ButtonType="Link" ShowSelectButton="true"
SelectText='<%# eval("ID") %>' />
```

Codebehind:

```
protected void mygridview_SelectedIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewSelectEventArgs e)
{
        //here you can do anything with the id
        string id = mygridview.Rows[e.NewSelectedIndex].Cells[1].Text;

        mdlPopup.Show();
}
```

Ajax popup:

```
<asp:Button id="btnShowPopup" runat="server" style="display:none" />
<ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender
ID="mdlPopup" 
runat="server" 
TargetControlID="btnShowPopup" 
PopupControlID="pnlPopup" 
CancelControlID="btnClose" 
BackgroundCssClass="Inactive" />
<asp:Panel ID="pnlPopup" runat="server" Width="500px" style="display:none;">
  <!--here you put any content that will go inside your popup-->
</asp:Panel>
```